# How to make a python script to run other files in separate terminals?

Tags: python, automation

I made some scraping files and to run them at the same time I usually open multiple terminals in VS code and write " python filename.py " for each file, there's any method to automate this process to call each file and run it?

Comment: Batch files? Powershell scripts? Or even a Python script with `subprocess` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the terms "Automation" and "each time I call it and run it" you have used to  ask for running it automatically within the program or by a python script.
For that you just simply use one module "OS MODULE"

```
import os
path = r'paste the path of the files'
filename = ['\file1.py', '\file2.py']
for file in filename:
    os.system('python '+path+file)
```

This code runs two files.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to run `python script1.py & python script2.py & python script3.py &`